# Accessing C function from java code in android

Tags: android

If we look at the /platform/external/bluetooth/bluedriod in the android source code , there are several files there with several c function. How do  I get access to these c function from my rooted android phone. I am doing some small experiments and need to call certain functions. I am wondering how  I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access native code by using NDK, [check this out](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: NDK code can be written in C/C++. But does this mean that I can access functions in /external/bluetooth?